# Passing an object as an argument in a fragment and modifying it in the second fragment causing first fragment to be modified as well

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

Here is the sample code https://github.com/pcoyne2/NewInstanceTest

When I open the second fragment from the first and pass the object referenced in the viewModel, and get the value from the arguments and modifying once I press back it is also modified in the first fragment

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message).setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("ViewModel", viewModel.testObject.value!!.toString())
        val objectToPass = viewModel.testObject.value!!
        Log.d("Argument", objectToPass.toString())
        val frag = SecondFragment.newInstance(objectToPass)
        (activity as MainActivity).addFragmentToBackStack(frag)
        }

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message).setText(viewModel.testObject.value!!.id)

        return view
    }
}




class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val testObject = MutableLiveData<TestObject>()
    init {
        testObject.value = TestObject()
    }
}
```

Second Fragment and Viewmodel

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SecondViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SecondViewModel::class.java)


        arguments?.get(OBJECT)?.let {
        Log.d("Argument", (it as TestObject).toString())
        viewModel.testObjectMutable.value = it as TestObject
        Log.d("ViewModel", viewModel.testObjectMutable.value.toString())
        viewModel.testObjectMutable.value?.id = "second"
        Log.d("UpdateSecViewModel", viewModel.testObjectMutable.value.toString())
        }

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message).setText(viewModel.testObjectMutable.value!!.id)


        return view
    }

    companion object {

        private const val OBJECT = "OBJECT"

        fun newInstance(testObject: TestObject) = SecondFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable(OBJECT, testObject)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
class SecondViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val testObjectMutable = MutableLiveData<TestObject>()

}
```

These are the logs that I added to show it is referencing the same memory

> D/ViewModel: com.pcoyne.testapplication.ui.main.TestObject@bd9a166
>
> D/Argument: com.pcoyne.testapplication.ui.main.TestObject@bd9a166
>
> D/Argument: com.pcoyne.testapplication.ui.main.TestObject@bd9a166
>
> D/ViewModel: com.pcoyne.testapplication.ui.main.TestObject@bd9a166
>
> D/UpdateSecViewModel:
> com.pcoyne.testapplication.ui.main.TestObject@bd9a166

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Mike M. Thanks I updated it